# how to uninstall vs 2010 sp1 beta

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I installed the SP1 beta for Visual Studio 2010 but when I open VS2010, it crashes. Is there a convenient method to uninstall sp1 without uninstalling vs 2010?

Answer (score 0):

"Programs and Features" should have the VS2010 SP1 Beta uninstaller and allow you to rollback the install. Otherwise you maybe have to uninstall all of VS and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do it now because VS2010 SP1 has been released ;)